# Preventing the hover effect

Tags: treeview, yui

I want the node expand button (the +/- one) to highlight only when the mouse is over the button itself but not when it is over the node text. By default, the button is highlighted in both cases. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

I'm using YUI 2.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a lot of ways, but I think it is more easy to edit CSS

```
.ygtvcell .ygtvtph
{
    background-color:url(http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/treeview/assets/skins/sam/treeview-sprite.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 -6400px !important;
}
```

Comment: Your rule has many problems.

1. The rule itself is invalid CSS.
2. .ygtvcell .ygtvtph will not target anything (.ygtvtph alone will).
3. Even after correcting the problems, the solution is not what I'm after since it prevents the +/- button from highlighting when the mouse is over it.